# After Use jQuery a href link not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<ul class="current">
<li>
    <a href="#nogo"><b>Products</b>
     <div class="select_sub show">
         <ul class="sub">
          <li class="sub_show"><a href="product/product.php">Add product</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
   </a>
   </li>
 </ul>


<ul class="select">
<li>
   <a href="#nogo"><b>Item</b>
     <div class="select_sub">
         <ul class="sub">
          <li><a href="itea/item.php">Add Item</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
   </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$("ul").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // if iI comment that line a href link work but navigation not work 
    var $this = $(this);
    var $siblings = $(this).siblings();

    $this.addClass("current").removeClass("select");
    $this.find('.select_sub').addClass('show');

    $siblings.removeClass("current").addClass('select');
    $siblings.find('.select_sub').addClass('show');

});
```

If I click on the `Add product` link, there is redirection on this url `product/product.php`

Thanks

Comment: `id="current"` shouldn't be same. Use either same class or different id's.

Comment: Mr Siva Charan ,if i have change id after that not working

Comment: @vikas Can you provide some more specifics about the surrounding code and exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Multiple Elements with same ID is not permitted in HTML.
Please remove ID and add Same class to all UL elements.

Comment: Mr Chinmaya003 , please see my edited question, after that a href link not work

Comment: Div is a block-level element. A is an inline element. It is not good practice to nest a block level element inside an inline element.

Comment: joeframbach, there any solution for it

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, when you say `e.preventDefault()`, you are actually telling to prevent `ul` default, which is nothing. Try to call `preventDefault()` directly on the link.

Comment: tofs yes you r right, after remove it e.preventDefault() jquery code not work

Comment: Try `$("ul.sub li a").preventDefault()` to stop the call to the link.